# Can I use formControl valueChanges to detect changes to a mat-chip-list?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `mat-chip-list` and want to detect when it changes ie: items added or removed.

I expected I could attach a form control to it and utilise the `valueChanges` observable to achieve this ie:

```
<mat-chip-list #chipList [formControl]="chipListCtrl">
```

```
chipListCtrl = new FormControl();
...
this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(tap(value => console.log('fruitCtrl: ', value))).subscribe();
```

However this is not logging anything to the console.

Refer to [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-chip-list?file=src/app/chips-autocomplete-example.ts) where the input control successfully works in this manner, but the chip list does not.

Is this possible and if so what do I need to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chip list does not emit valueChanges because you are not updating it's value. You are updating the `fruits` array which is in no way connected to your formControl.

I've forked your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-chip-list-5qfxfn) so that the events update the value of your `chipListCtrl` and the contents of the `mat-chip-list` are using `chipListCtrl.value` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need formControl to detect changes in mat-chip-list.
According to the documentation - https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api,
you can directly use (change) eventemitter.

@Output()
change: EventEmitter

Event emitted when the selected chip list value has been changed by the user.

Comment: I have tried that but can't get the change event to fire at all. Even the documentation for it is ambiguous as it refers to selection - 'Event emitted when the *selected* chip list value has been changed by the user.' Additionally it is more convenient if I have an observable of the changes. See stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-chip-list-change-event?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
 constructor() {
    this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(tap(value => console.log('fruitCtrl: ', value))).subscribe();
    this.chipListCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(tap(value => console.log('chipListCtrl: ', value))).subscribe();

    this.filteredFruits = this.fruitCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(null),
        map((fruit: string | null) => fruit ? this._filter(fruit) : this.allFruits.slice()));
  }
```